# Azure Mobile App Easy Tables - Getting Started

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

I'm making a Xamarin.Android mobile app with an Azure Mobile Apps backend to store a table. The table will contain the names and email addresses that users enter into the app, and the app will also display the names and email addresses listed in the table.

I created an Easy Table in the Mobile App blade of the Azure Portal but I don't understand how that fits into the big picture. What are the next steps for writing code that can get the information into the table? I have been referred to articles on the Azure website such as [this one](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#publish-server-project) that say I need to create a .NET backend to make a table but how does that relate to the table I made using Easy Tables?

Can someone explain to me what I need to do next to accomplish what I want to do? Or at least point me to some more articles that will get me on my way?

Answer (score 1):

The best idea is to go through the tutorial which will tie it all together - both the client side and the server side.  The tutorial set are:

- [Getting Started](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started/)
- [Data Access and Offline Sync](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started-offline-data/)
- [Authentication](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started-users/)
- [Push Notifications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started-push/)

I've linked the Xamarin.Android version.   Examining the code as you go and understanding what is happening will assist your investigation.  Once you've got through the tutorial, the client and server HOWTO documents will assist in some of the additional things you might choose to do:

- [Client SDK for Xamarin.Android](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/)
- [Server SDK for Node.js / Easy Tables](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/)

It's important to note that when you are using Easy Tables, the code underneath is Node.js / JavaScript - not ASP.NET (you got pointed to the ASP.NET HOWTO)

Comment: So the code that is created when I create an Easy Table in the Azure Portal is actually Node.js / JavaScript? If so, is this code in the server project that the Getting Started walkthrough had me configure?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Azure portal you can create a basic app that will show you how to work with Easy Tables.

You just have to go to `APP DEPLOYMENT` section in you `App Service` and select `Quickstart` there you can select the platform or technology that you are using (Xamarin.Android in this case) and configure de connection, the table Api associate with the EasyTable and download the app.

You will have now a basic CRUD app, from there you can extend the functionality or add other things.